# WiFi adapter startup delay causing network discovery to turn itself off?

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-networking

I've been trying for some time to troubleshoot my network problems. I have a desktop PC with a TP-LINK Archer T9E WiFi adapter.

One thing to note is that after Windows 10 boots the WiFi takes a few seconds to start. Some programs start faster than the WiFi and sometimes it causes mild annoyances (like Razer Synapse not being able to connect to the Razer server and asking me for the password).

On the same network there is a laptop. It can connect to my computer to see my shared files. However, I can connect to it in only 10% of cases. I have not been able to determine when it works and when it doesn't. I've checked and all the required services are running and starting on automatic.

I thought I had checked if Network Discovery was turned on. I checked it again today and it was turned off. I turned it on and restarted. Checked again, it was turned off again. If I just sign out and then sign in again (no restart) it seems to work and I can access the networked laptop.

So what I want to ask is - could it be possible that Windows is turning off Network Discovery because of the delay in starting the WiFi? If so, is there something I can do so that the WiFi starts faster?

Answer (score 3):

try this：

enable the group policy: **Always wait for the network at computer startup and logon**

1. run the group policy editor as administrator
2. find the group policy path: **Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\System\Logon**
3. enable this policy
4. Then run the services management as administrator
5. set the required services as **automatic(Delayed Start)**
6. reboot the machine

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it wasn't enough on its own but it got me searching for other stuff and in the end I found a combination that works (even if it's not ideal). First I did as you said. It didn't work so I also ran this command: "**gpupdate /force**". Still not working. I had set up Windows to not require a password to log me in. Thinking that maybe imputing a password would give the WiFi enough time to start, I set it up to require a password. Still not enough, as the programs were loading in the background before I could input the password.

Comment: (continued)  So I went into **Settings->Accounts->Sign In options** and disabled **Use my sign-in info to automatically finish setting up my device and reopen my apps after an update or restart**. Now if I wait in the Logon Screen for the WiFi to start and then enter my password everything works OK and I can access the network computers. Oh, one more thing. Along the way I also added a "fMinimizeConnections" DWORD registry key with value zero in HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WcmSvc\GroupPolicy. Not sure if that did anything, but it might have.

Comment: yes, I think it is also need to make sure that the network connection has been completed before the you logon. And thanks for your sharing.